# Pausing mpg123 through subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

My problem is that i want to run mpg123 in the background and play/ pause a mp3-file.

I opened the subprocess like this:

```
player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "alarm.mp3", "-C"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

However, when I try to pause mpg123 with

```
player.stdin.write("s")
```

it only returns a number which is based on the length of the string (in this case: 1)

[---> Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct7AA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! Apaarently you have to flush the stdin after every input.
Working code (note that I switched to mplayer, because with mpg123 it wasn't working):

```
player = subprocess.Popen(["mplayer", "/music.mp3"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
time.sleep(10)
player.stdin.write("pause")
player.stdin.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

mpg123 requires a terminal-like stdin, PIPE won't work. Have a try:

```
import os
import pty
import subprocess
import time

master, slave = os.openpty()

p = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-C', 'music.mp3'], stdin=master)
time.sleep(3)
os.write(slave, 's')
time.sleep(3)
os.write(slave, 's')
time.sleep(6)
os.write(slave, 'q')
```

Answer (score 0):

mpg123 requires a terminal-like stdin; as compliments to Xhui Xiong. I did get a TypeError "a bytes-like object is required, not str".
This is solved by typecasting to byte:
os.write(slave, b's')
.. Tested and works for me.